# Integer points on parabola

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry

I'm intrested in studying integer points on quadratic equations:

$$Q(x,y)=ax^2+bxy+cy^2+dx+ey+f=0, \quad (a,b,c,d,e,f\in\mathbb{Z}).$$

Using Lagrange method it is possible to reduce it in a *Pell equation*

$$X^2-DY^2=N,$$

with

$$
X=(b^2-4ac)y+E, \quad Y=2ax+by+d,\quad N=E^2-F(b^2-4ac),
$$

easy to solve algorithmically if $Q(x,y)$ is not a parabola $(\Delta=b^2-4ac\neq 0)$.

How can I determine integer points on a quadratic equation with $\Delta =0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $b^2-4ac=0$ and $a,b,c$ are not all zero, then you first transform the equation into
$$
A(\alpha x+\beta y)^2+B(\alpha x+\beta y)+C(\gamma x+\delta y)+D=0, \begin{pmatrix}\alpha&\beta\\\gamma&\delta\end{pmatrix}\in SL(2,\mathbb{Z})
$$
and hence $AX^2+BX+CY+D=0$.  Completing the square, you can further reduce it to the form $A^2X^2+CY+D=0$.  Then it is basically constraining $X$ by $(AX)^2\equiv -D\pmod{C}$ (which may or may not have any solutions $X_0$) and thus for each $X=Cm+X_0$ ($m\in\mathbb{Z}$, $(AX_0)^2\equiv-D\pmod{C}$), obtain the resulting $Y$.

Comment: The existence of $ \alpha , \beta , \gamma , \delta$ is given by the spectral theorem?

Comment: You can, but it is an overkill.  $\begin{pmatrix}2a & b\\b & 2c\end{pmatrix}$ has nontrivial kernel, and since it is in $M_2(\mathbb{Q})$ we can choose a generator with coprime integer entries.  Then Bezout to get the other two entries.

Comment: Thank you very much!